# How to import a third-party framework into my Swift project?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-frameworks, ddmathparser

I am trying to import the DDMathParser framework into my Swift app. I tried following the installation instructions from the DDMathParser wiki, though it did not work:

> DDMathParser is packaged as a Swift framework.
>
> Add DDMathParser.xcodeproj to your workspace and link MathParser.framework into your app.

(Link: https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Installing)

Here's what I did:

1. I dragged in the .xcodeproj file into my project (from Finder to Xcode), and the file shows up under my project in the sidebar.
2. I went to my project settings and clicked the '+' under "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" and neither "MathParser.framework" or "DDMathParser.framework" are showing up in the list of available frameworks.
3. I tried building my application after adding the xcodeproj, but the framework files are still not showing up.

What am I doing wrong, or how do I correctly install this framework?

(Using Xcode 7.2.1)

Comment: Ensure you create an Xcode workspace for your project.

Comment: I believe I have a workspace for my project, [does this look right](http://i.imgur.com/2J1dWkj.png)?

Comment: It might. If you have a workspace, and there is a framework project within it, you should be able to add it via: in the target editor, select your app target, click Tab "Build Phases", open section "Link Binary With Libraries" and click the (+) button ("Add Items"). Then a sheet should roll down with a file selection dialog, also showing a "Workspace" virtual folder. In this "Workspace" folder, there should be your third party framework.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I followed your steps [and I got to this point](http://i.imgur.com/2zXNyZW.png), where the action sheet rolls down, but there is no "Workspace folder", just the standard OS X folder and the Developer Frameworks folder. I am wondering whether the issue might be the fact that the downloaded source files (from DDMathParser) do not contain any ".framework" files.. perhaps I must build them first somehow in order to generate the .framework file?

Comment: It seems, you don't have a workspace yet. A workspace bundle has the extension `. xcworkspace`. The workspace bundle is oftentimes located in the same folder where the main projects file (`.xcodeproj`)  resides.

Comment: Hmm, I am able to build my app and interact with it (without the 3rd-party framework), so I would assume all the necessary "built-in" files and folders should all be there. Am I supposed to add a .xcworkspace bundle manually somehow? [Here is the contents of my project folder.](http://i.imgur.com/xp0lE4I.png)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your project using the "Terminal app"
once at the root folder type `pod init` a `Podfile` will be created you can open it with `nano Podfile` and add these changes with updated paths to your specific project.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
xcodeproj 'YOURPROJECT.xcodeproj'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'DDMathParser'
```

Then save your file.

type `pod install` and hit enter.

Now open your new .xcworkspace that was created. In any file that you want to use the `DDMathParser framework` just add `import DDMathParser` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

1) $ sudo gem install cocoapods (gem will get installed in Ruby inside System library)

2) create a xcode project

3) Open terminal

4) cd "path to your project root directory"

5) pod init

6) open -e podfile (podfile will get open in text mode. Initially it will be emppty put     the follwoing line of  code.)

7) pod 'DDMathParser'  (Cocoapods Podfile name ) // This is example

8) pod install

CocoaPods 0.36 and above will support for swift

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as it helped me a lot of times:

1. Create a workspace eg. I named it Beacon
2. Create a project in it  e.g. I create a project named BeaconDemo
3. Create a Podfile in the folder where you created the  workspace
4. The contents of Podfile :

   workspace 'Beacon'

   xcodeproj 'BeaconDemo/BeaconDemo.xcodeproj'

   platform :ios, '8.0'

   use_frameworks!

   pod 'NearbyMessages', '~> 0.9'

   pod 'EstimoteSDK', '~> 3.8'

   pod 'Charts', '~> 2.2'

   pod 'GoogleMobileAds', '~> 7.6'
5. Open terminal and go to your workspace
6. Hit pod install
7. Then open the workspace that you have created e.g. over here as in step 1